# How to use HTML style in a string?

Tags: powershell

suppose i have a string like this:

```
string = 
"<style>li { list-style: none; }</style>
<li><b>Source:</b> $Source</li>
<li><b>Security:</b> $Security</li>
"
```

I still get bullet points

i cant use it like this because the string is already wrapped in double quotes due to $variables like `$Source`

```
<li style="list-style: none;">
```

I get `Unexpected token 'list-style:' in expression or statement.` because i cant use double quotes

so my only choice is using it like this:

```
<style>li { list-style: none; }</style>
```

but it doesnt get applied...why is that?

UPDATE: To clarify, i want to utilize the listing mechanism WITHOUT bullet points showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set string variables with single quotes, those values can contain literal double quotes. The problem with this is that everything within the single quotes will be treated as a literal string, which means `$Source` and `$Security` would not get expanded. If you are going to use double quotes and variables within the same string, I suggest escaping the inner double quotes with a backtick.

```
$string = 
"<ul style=`"list-style-type:none; padding-left:0`">
<li><b>Source:</b> $Source</li>
<li><b>Security:</b> $Security</li>
</ul>
"
```

The `list-style-type:none` property sets the list item marker to none. '`padding-left:0` removes the left indentation of the list.

To test, just output the contents to a file (`s.html`) and open the file from a browser.

```
$string | Set-Content s.html
```

If you are testing this in an email client like Outlook, results may vary. Outlook  does not support `list-style-type: none`.

If you just need a list with bolded properties for purposes of reading in an email client, you can simplify this. Then use `Send-Mailmessage` with the `-BodyAsHtml` switch with the following string as the body.

```
$string = "
<b>Sources:</b> $source<br>
<b>Security:</b> $security<br>
"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192990/discussion-on-answer-by-adminofthings-how-to-use-html-style-in-a-string). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to reflect any insights gleaned from the discussion.